# add a title banner at the top of a div in CSS only

Tags: css, html

I am trying to add a title which will show much like a banner for that dive with text in. like the below image.

[image]

The problem is I need to set the title text in css.
I have a single div with the content in thats it. I cannot change the HTML code to add things.

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't put content in your CSS, if it's a title or some other piece of content it should be in HTML.

Comment: Is the title text already in the div and you just want to change the look of it or the text is not even there and you need to add it?

Comment: So what *is* the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with `before` pseudo-element, something like this :

```
.your_div:before {
    content: "Your DIV title";
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    background: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But it won't be compatible with old browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div div{

 
   background-color:brown;
   border:1px solid white;
   text-align:center;
    }
    
    .title{
    height:40px;
   padding-bottom:30px;
    background-color:whitesmoke !important;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .main{
      border-radius:10px;
    border:2px solid red;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 5px 2px black;
    height:content-width;
    
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
  <html>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
    <h2>my title</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div><p>first div</p>
    </div>
    
    <div><p>second div</p>
    </div>
    
    </div>
     </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: A little description on why this code works would be helpful to the person who asked the question.